# On rails configuration, use systematically the latest installed version of Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, upgrade, rails-console

Since when I execute “bundle install” I get the message error:

```
Gem::InstallError: devise requires Ruby version >= 2.1.0.
An error occurred while installing devise (4.2.0), and Bundler cannot continue.
```

Which is the simplest way, to put as a default version, the last one (ruby 2.3.3 that I already installed), as it seems that I still use the old version, as indicated on Rails configuration
[image: Rails_configuration]

Through my different searches on google, I couldn’t manage to find a simple solution; As I will not use anymore the old versions, a solution like RVM seems too complicated, my wish is just to use the latest installed version of Ruby, as the default version on Rails
PS: I am on windows
Many thanks

Comment: Maybe this is an option: http://railsinstaller.org/en

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`RVM` does not support `windows` [RVM FAQS](https://rvm.io/support/faq#does-rvm-work-on-windows-will-it-in-the-future)

You can use [pik](https://github.com/vertiginous/pik) for managing ruby version on windows though this project is no longer maintained.

For simple solution may be you can remove folder that has been created for ruby older version on your pc like `c:/Ruby-1.9`.

If you really serious about developing app using ruby, then use `linux` that will make your developer life much easier. There are many `gems` that need [Ruby DevKit](https://corlewsolutions.com/articles/article-22-install-ruby-devkit-on-windows-7) On windows. Hope it will help someone.